# Embedding YouTube Channel Details using PHP

Tags: php, api, google-api, youtube, request

I want to create a webpage on my site that acts as a gallery for users YouTube channels, so it will display their channel profile picture, channel title and possibly a few other bits of info.

The way thought to achieve this was to get the user to insert their YouTube Channel URL when they sign up (if they have one) which I have a function that will separate the channel name from the URL and store the URL and the channel name in my MySQL database.

With this info can I use the YouTube API to request the profile picture and other data using PHP? I have setup my YouTube API and have my API key but there is so much junk and info on the YouTube pages that I can't figure it out and I'm not familiar with JSON.

Question: How can I request data from YouTube using the API and the Channel URL/Channel Name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Channels:list method to search for a collection of channel resources that will match your request criteria

You can use **forUsername** or **id** request parameter as one of your filters for channels:list method.

> **forUsername**
>
> string
>
> The forUsername parameter specifies a YouTube username, thereby requesting the channel associated with that username.
>
> ---
>
> **id**
>
> string
>
> The id parameter specifies a comma-separated list of the YouTube channel ID(s) for the resource(s) that are being retrieved. In a channel resource, the id property specifies the channel's YouTube channel ID.

**Note:**
Specify exactly only one of the filters available for the channels:list request

Channel:list method will return a response body with the following structure:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": etag,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "prevPageToken": string,
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": integer,
    "resultsPerPage": integer
  },
  "items": [
    channel Resource
  ]
}
```

> items[]
>
> A list of channels that match the request criteria.

For a list of information/data that you could access in the channels resource object,
Please refer here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels

---

Quickstart reference on how to use Youtube API in PHP:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/php

---

Channels:List method information could be found here:

- This contains request and response parameters.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list